# How to use Script component(SSIS) in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to use script component in Azure data factory as we have in SSIS? I want to use c# script to transform data before loading in to the destination. my source is SQL db.

Comment: I do not want to execute SSIS package through ADF.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ADF doesnt have a script task similar to SSIS for C# code execution.(The script task in ADF is w.r.t SQL code)
You can try leveraging the dataflow tasks to reciprocate the code in flow format else you would have to leverage Azure function/ Azure batch to execute your code which you can call via ADF